# Deploying my C# application with my database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, installation

I have written a C# application that uses a SQL Server 2005 database.

I would like to install it on a computer that does not have SQL Server installed.

What can I do ?

Comment: Can you be any more specific? What is your deployment process? If the target machine needs to have the database on it, and it doesn't have SQL Server, can you install it on that machine?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options:

1. Have your application connect to SQL Server on another machine, or
2. If you want the db on the same box as the application and don't have SQL Server 2005 available, you can install SQL Server 2005 Express (which is free).

[SQL Server 2005 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21844)

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server will have to be *accessible* from the machine you are installing your application to. So you'll need to install it *somewhere* - be it on a local machine or on a remote server visible through the network.

You may also need to run SQL DDL scripts to create a database schema that your application expects.

If your application is not a "real" client-server application (in a sense that multiple clients concurrently access the same server), you may want to consider SQL Server Compact (or some other embedded database), so you can distribute the database directly with your application.